# Is there a way to slice arrays in mksh?

Tags: arrays, shell, mksh

There is `${name//pattern/string}` and `${name:pos:len}` for strings but I haven't found any similar documentation for manipulating arrays.

So far I've just been using shift and/or unset for simple manipulation. The only other plausible alternative would be to loop over the values and reconstitute a new array but that isn't desirable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mksh developer here ;-)

This is not yet implemented currently, to answer your question. It *has* been on the TODO for a while already, going as far as to be a comment in the source code file in question, so it will probably materialise some day (a good chance to add it is when we’ll have multi-dimensional and associative arrays added, which prompts a partial rewrite of the code in question anyway).